# How to end a program properly with threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a class which pulls items from a queue and then runs code on it. I also have code in the main function that adds items to the queue for processing.

For some reason, the program doesn't want to end properly.

Here is the code:

```
class Downloader(Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True: 
            download_file(self.queue.get())
            self.queue.task_done()

def spawn_threads(Class, amount):   
    for t in xrange(amount): 
        thread = Class(queue)
        thread.setDaemon = True
        thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spawn_threads(Downloader, 20)
    for item in items: queue.put(item)
    #not the real code, but simplied because it isn't relevant

    print 'Done scanning. Waiting for downloads to finish.'
    queue.join()
    print 'Done!'
```

The program waits for it to finish properly at the `queue.join()` and prints `Done!`, but something keeps the program from closing which i can't seem to put my finger on. I'd assume it was the `while True` loop, but i thought setting the threads as daemons was meant to solve that.

Comment: the `while True` will keep running infinitely, it should be stopped and then the Thread will terminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are not using [`setDaemon()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.setDaemon) correctly**. As a result, none of the `Downloader` threads are daemon threads.

Instead of

```
thread.setDaemon = True
```

write

```
thread.setDaemon(True)
```

or

```
thread.daemon = True
```

([The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) seem to imply that the latter is the preferred spelling in Python 2.6+.)